# Stripe: Change currency depending on location?

Tags: geolocation, stripe-payments, location, currency, checkout

I have set USD as the default currency on my product but added 4 more currencies (EUR, GBP, AUD and CHF). How can I make these swap depending on the customers physical location. For the sake of an example, let's assume you are from Germany and want to buy my product - I want your displayed currency to automatically set itself to EUR during checkout.

```
    <script>
    var stripe = Stripe( 
    "pk_live_51LzJXLEOzrDWipQGPi4HbwFv1xxGw7wty7jifLYuKU9VwfpNvCb1DIfDohwHfJSk9VKQ1BhdpDIR8bVnjA9fEzR200y8nDoKqj"
    )
    
    document.getElementById("checkout").addEventListener("click", function(){
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            lineItems: [
      {
        price: 'price_1MKKUgEOzrDWipQGG2tTXjxV',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
            mode: 'payment',
    successUrl: `https://galusfilms.com/luts=success`,
    cancelUrl: `https://galusfilms.com/luts=cancel`,
        })
            .then(function(result){
                
                
                });
    })
    
    </script>
```

This it what my current checkout session looks like, what do I need to add? I have very little experience in coding and all of this stuff and because of this I would really appreciate some help...

Answer (score 0):

Since the price you've created supports multiple currencies, Stripe Checkout automatically localizes and presents the local currency to your customers in either USD, EUR, GBP, AUD or CHF in this case.

To test your currency presentment in AUD, when creating the Checkout session, you can pass `test+location_AU@example.com` in the `customer_email` parameter. Your code will look something like this:

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  line_items: [{price: '{{PRICE_ID}}', quantity: 1}],
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
  customer_email: 'test+location_AU@example.com',
});
```

To see more details on how to test currency presentments you can visit [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/present-local-currencies#test-currency-presentment) document.